# How can I implement individual django session for individual users visiting my page without user registration?

Tags: django, session

I am making a restaurant-ordering website where customers open the site from their own smartphone and order food. I don't want them to have their own user accounts but the website must recognize these users(from cookies or something). In short, different users must have their own sessions provided they open the website from their devices. Is this possible in Django?

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate a unqiue anonymous user id(like `anonymous_user_id`) on client side for a user, first time user visit the website and save it in cookie for a api domain (if same domain of client side otherwise save it in local storage and explicitly pass it in headers or query param).

On backend side, you can create a middleware in Django to check whether a cookie or header exist, and create or get user from anonymous user store(i.e Database table) by id, and load that user in `request.user`, so that for you rapplication, an authenticated user will be `request.user`.